# DateTimeFormatter auto-corrects invalid (syntactically possible) calendar date

Tags: java, parsing, date, formatting, java-time

Java `DateTimeFormatter` throws an exception for when you try a date that goes outside of a possible range, for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
String dateString = "12/32/2015";
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf);
```

will throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12/32/2015' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
```

But when I enter an invalid calendar date that is still syntactically possible by their standards, it autocorrects it to be a valid date, for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
String dateString = "2/31/2015";
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf);
```

it successfully parses but autocorrects to `2015-02-28`. I don't want this behavior, I want it to still throw an exception when the date is not a valid calendar date. Is there a built-in option I can set for that to happen, or do I really have to try to manually sift out these instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `STRICT` resolver style:

```
import static java.time.format.ResolverStyle.STRICT;

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu").withResolverStyle(STRICT);
```

By default, `ofPattern` uses [a `SMART` resolver style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) which will use reasonable defaults.

Note that I have used `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`, i.e. [YEAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR) instead of [YEAR_OF_ERA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR_OF_ERA). Assuming you are in a Gregorian calendar system, the two are equivalent for years in the current era (year 1 or greater). The difference is explained in more details in the links above.

Comment: This gives me a different exception:

`Text '2/28/2015' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=28, YearOfEra=2015, MonthOfYear=2},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: The message is telling you that the era is missing - in strict mode it no longer defaults. You need to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, IsoEra.CE.getValue())` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-

Comment: Can't we simply replace `yyyy` by `uuuu` in this case?

Comment: @assylias changing it to uuuu worked! What is the significance of that, why does it work? If the above answer is changed with an explanation I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @aconkey added explanation