# ZonedDateTime: I would like parse() to fail on invalid date

Tags: datetime, java-8

I guess I just expected this to give me a parsing exception, but it didn't. I would like the parse to fail if the date is invalid. (That's what I need to know)

Added note: Using Feb. 30th as an invalid date: (In fact, what I need to do is receive five strings; year, month, day, hour, minute, which I assembly into `str` (below) and see if they come together as a valid date-time (in `ZONE_ID`).

```
String ZONE_NAME = "America/Los_Angeles";
ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of(ZONE_NAME);
String ldtfPattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm";
DateTimeFormatter localDateTimeFormatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ldtfPattern);

String str = "2016/02/30 21:09";

try {
    zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, localDateTimeFormatter().withZone(ZONE_ID));
} catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
    return null;
}
return zdt;
```

The string value of zdt after the parse above is
`2016-02-29T21:09-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]`

Comment: The `str` you have there matches the format, so no exception is thrown. If you change it to something that doesn't (such as `"2016-02-30 21:09"`), you will indeed get a `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: @Mureinik I got downvoted for this?  It's February 30th, which is invalid, and I want that to fail.  Or I want to know that.

Comment: Oh, good point! Downvote removed, although I suggest editing it into the question to hightlight it.

Comment: @Mureinik, Okay.  I added a note paragraph to clarify my idea of "invalid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little birdie told me to try using `withResolverStyle()` set to `STRICT`.  With that, the only other trick I needed to make this work was to incorporate the [era into my year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308216/903343).  So the changes to the above are:

```
String ldtfPattern = "uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm";
```

and

```
zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, 
                getLocalDateTimeFormatter().withZone(ZONE_ID).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT));
```

And this is working for me.